# how to load config folder in nestjs-config?

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-config

I use ConfigService in nestjs

**my code**

app.module.ts

ConfigModule.forRoot({
isGlobal: true,
load: [
databaseConfig,
redisConfig,
appConfig,
...
],
}),

too much lines in load property.

so how can load one time?

how to read folder in loader?

my folder is like this.

- config

  - database.config.ts
  - redis.config.ts
  - app.config.ts
  - ...

i can't solve this problem.
i read nestjs doc but i cant find.

i read nestjs doc but i cant find.